# What's the recommended bitrate for Background Music in iPhone Games?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, music, ios

What is the recommended bitrate for Background Music in iPhone Games?

Comment: Just to clear up confusion I had: BGM is background music.

Comment: I edited the question to clear it up even more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all honesty, it's probably down to what sounds best at the lowest bitrate.

So if you had music at 192kbps but you could still get it sounding decent without a whole lot of quality loss at, say, 64kbps, then you've got no reason not to use the 64kbps version.

It might be worth having a bunch of different bitrates of the same song and see which "sounds" the best, whilst reducing the bitrate. If you've got some 8-bit retro sounds in the music you could get away with fairly low bitrates, but probably less so with a piece of music with a wide variety of sounds and textures (e.g. a classical composition, with full percussion, and synths and basses on top).

Just as an extra, if you're not certain about what sounds correct at a low bitrate, I'd suggest talking to an audio producer or if that's not possible then just ask the guys at [Audio-Video Production SE](http://avp.stackexchange.com) those guys definitely know their audio :)

Answer (score 0):

Like Ray Dey said, you need to make the call on quality vs size. Remember the [project triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aProject_Triangle.svg)?

The same applies to audio. You can have good quality audio that doesn't take up a lot of space, but you'll have to manage streaming it and you're often limited to a set number of streaming channels on non-PC hardware. You can have good quality without streaming, but it will take up a lot of memory, etc.

Something to check out, if you are working with composers who would be comfortable writing the music in trackers, you can use FMOD (iPod/Pad/Phone and PSP license is listed under "Casual" on their [Sales Page](http://www.fmod.org/index.php/sales) and is $500 flat) and load .MOD, .XM, and .IT. You can have high quality samples and fine-grain control over the flow of music.